# Unable to Send Emails using Amazon Workmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-workmail

I am trying to integrate Amazon Workmail using SMTP (following these instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP.html). However, keep on getting

```
535 Authentication credentials invalid
```

exception. I have tried various email clients (java), such as *simple-java-mai*l & *commons-email* but to no avail. Facing similar issue when trying to add AWS Workmail account in Outlook (Windows machine), however, strange enough it works fine in Andriod Outlook App. I have tried by URL encoding the credentials but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It was the password. Make sure the password only contains a-z, A-Z and 0-9 chars only.

Comment: In addition to what @w-khattak said, we found that you should also make sure that your firewall is enabled if you are using a Mac. If it is not on (for some reason) you will not be able to send emails.